# Как поменять код, чтобы выводить результат в столбик

Tags: python

Я читаю программу из файла и она выводит результат  в виде списка строк:

```
with open('1_lst.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    print(text)  # "[1,2,3,4,5]"
```

Мне нужно вывести результат в виде:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Comment: Что, опять?! Был же вчера только такой вопрос, всем форумом отвечали (

Comment: @CrazyElf, то вчера, а сегодня надо заново

Answer (score 1):

```
text = "[1,2,3,4,5]"
text = text[1:-1]

for el in text.split(","):
    print(el)
```

с помощью `text[1:-1]` убираем квадратные скобки. с помощью `text.split(",")` разделяем строку и печатаем по элемента.

либо заменяем `,` на перенос строки `\n`

```
print(text.replace(",", "\n"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте пройтись по нему циклом for.

```py
with open('1_lst.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read().split(",")
    # print(text)  # "[1,2,3,4,5]"
    for i in text:
        print(i)
```

Comment: у автора строка, а не список

Comment: ну тогда .split(",")